# PHP/MYSQL Create Sort Algorithm Data Schema

Tags: mysql, algorithm, logic

My apologies in advance if this does not seem like a proper SO question. However, I can't find the answer anywhere else.

I want to be able to sort results by an algorithm that ranks results based on different columns or variables using a rule.  My intuition is that using the built in MYSQL ORDER BY is much faster than manipulating the record collection once it is returned.  I have used Indexes in MYSQL to speed up sorting on a field or alternatively two fields.  But I don't know how to create a rule or formula that weights two fields and prioritizes and imposes logic on the weights.

**For example:**  Say I have a table of reviews.  I would like to create an algorithm that sorts these reviews based on the combined weighting of different variables with a bit of logic thrown in.

**As in example:** Return results edited today first.  With all other results, return based  50% on the reputation of the author and 50% on when the review was 
created.

Table reviews:

```
id|reviewtext|lastedited|datecreated|authorid
```

Table authors

```
id|name|reputation
```

MYSQL/PHP:

```
$SQL = "SELECT r.*, a.* FROM `reviews` r
LEFT JOIN `authors` a
on = r.authorid= a.id
WHERE reviewtext LIKE '%str%'
ORDER BY lastedited DESC datecreated DESC reputation DESC";
```

would order first by lastedited, then by datecreated etc.

How do I use a more complicated formula with logic weights etc.?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expressions in your ORDER BY clause -

```
SELECT r.*, a.*
FROM reviews r
INNER JOIN authors a
    ON r.authorid = a.id
WHERE reviewtext LIKE '%str%'
ORDER BY
    IF(lastedited >= CURRENT_DATE, lastedited, '0000-00-00') DESC,
    (SOME EXPRESSION EVALUATING DATE AND REPUTATION) DESC
```